# Flutter/Dart, cannot set a variable to a value from a json asset

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter

I have a json file sitting in my assets  folder. The json file holds the state to the switches on my settings page. I have some code the will read t5he json file and decoded it.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "ThemeColour" : "blue",
    "HighlightState" : false,
    "DisplayState" : true
}
```

**Code:**

```
class Settings {
  final String themeColour;
  final bool highlightState;
  final bool displayState;

  Settings(this.themeColour, this.highlightState,this.displayState);
}

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new SettingsPageState();
}

class SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  //---------------------------------------
  //Load JSON savedSettings
  //---------------------------------------
  Future loadSavedSettings() async {
    String jsonSavedSettings = await _loadSettingsAsset();
    Settings savedSettings = _parseJsonForSettings(jsonSavedSettings);

    print(savedSettings.displayState);
  }

  Future<String> _loadSettingsAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/savedSettings.json');
  }

  Settings _parseJsonForSettings(String jsonString) {
    Map decoded = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return Settings(decoded['themeColour'], decoded['HighlightState'], decoded['DisplayState']);
  }
  //---------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadSavedSettings();

    bool _highlightState = false;
    bool _displayState = false;
```

When I have the `print` in loadSavedSettings(), it is printing out the correct value. However I cannot seem to get it so that the two booleans at the bottom of the code are equal to the respective values in the json file.

```
bool _highlightState = HighlightState value in json file;
bool _displayState = DisplayState value in json file;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the value and use `setState(...)` so that `build()` is executed again after the values are set.

```
  Future loadSavedSettings() async {
    String jsonSavedSettings = await _loadSettingsAsset();
    Settings savedSettings = _parseJsonForSettings(jsonSavedSettings);

    print(savedSettings.displayState);
    setState(() {
      _highlightState = savedSettings.highlightState;
      _displayState = savedSettings.displayState;
    });
  }
```

This code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadSavedSettings();

    bool _highlightState = false;
    bool _displayState = false;
```

needs to be changed to

```
  bool _highlightState = false;
  bool _displayState = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSavedSettings();
  }    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: I just get the following error on `_highlightState = savedSettings['HighlightState'];` : `Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::Settings'`

Comment: I missed that you wrapped the data in a class. You have a typo (unrelated) `    return Settings(decoded['themeColour'], ` should be `['ThemeColour'],` (uppercase `T`)
 `

Comment: Glad to hear. .